# How can I execute function returning type from discriminated union

Tags: f#

I am not sure how to write this statement.

> let dealPlayer() = Hit(Two; Spades)
>
> Error     This expression was expected to have type

```
type Suit = | Spades
            | Diamonds
            | Clubs
            | Hearts

type Face = |Two | Three | Four | Five 
            | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
            | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = {Face: Face; Suit: Suit}

type Deal = | Hand of Card * Card
            | Hit of Card

let dealPlayer() = Hit(Two; Spades)
```

I'm still new to F#.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want `dealPlayer` to always return the hard-coded *two of spades*, it's done like this:

```
let dealPlayer () = Hit { Face = Two; Suit = Spades }
```

The `dealPlayer` function has the inferred type `unit -> Deal`.

`Card` is a [record type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx), so you'll need to to use a *record expression* to create a value of that type. That's the `{ Face = Two; Suit = Spades }` part.

The `Hit` part is the *case constructor* for the `Hit` case of `Deal`.